# Why does my WPF converter “miss” the last character in the TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, converters

I’m building a WPF application using Visual Studio 2019. One of the views of this application has a `TextBox` inside of it, which is binded to a property of its `DataContext`. The code related to the `TextBox` is this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Alpha" Text="{Binding Model.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                              ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Converter={StaticResource ToUpper}}" />
```

As you can guess, the `ToUpper` converter makes the text inside the `TextBox` uppercase. When I write something inside the `TextBox`, I see it’s uppercase, so the converter seems to work. So far so good, but the problem is that the last character seems to be “missing” during the conversion. I say that because when I write something in the `TextBox`, text that is made uppercase by the converter, in the code-behind of the view:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   Alpha.KeyDown += Alpha_KeyDown;
}

private void Alpha_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e) {
   if (e.Key == Key.Return) {
      var a = Alpha.text;
   }
}
```

I find that the `a` variable stores the exact same text of the `TextBox`, but with the last character lowercase. For example, if I write “abcde” inside the `TextBox`, the converter makes it uppercase and the view renders “ABCDE”, but `a` is set to “ABCDe”.

The `Convert()` method of the converter is this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
   var myString = value as string;
   return text != null ? text.ToUpper() : "No text";
}
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KeyDown event is triggered before the Text property changes. The following can make it clear:

```
private void Alpha_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Key == Key.Return)
 {
  Debug.WriteLine("After return: " + Alpha.Text);
 }
 else
 {
  Debug.WriteLine(Alpha.Text + e.Key.ToString().ToUpper());
 }
}
```

So, by this time Alpha.Text haven't updated with the new key and hence not converted.

Comment: To be honest, `Alpha.Text` is printed uppercase inside the `if`.

Comment: Yes, it's just that the last key character won't be there during key down for that particular key. That's why that key is explicitly appended into my handler.

Comment: But if I press *Enter*, this would’t be another key down?

Comment: Yes. In that case, Alpha.Text should write the complete upper case text as per following condition:  
if (e.Key == Key.Return)
 {
  Debug.WriteLine("After return: " + Alpha.Text);
 }

Comment: @PineCode, please mark it as answer if this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your converter changes the value as it transfers via the binding mechanism between the textbox text and the viewmodel property.

To be clear.

It does not change the value as it is typed.

You are using the keydown event to grab the data out the textbox directly:

```
private void FiscalCodeEb_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e) 
 {
   if (e.Key == Key.Return) {
       var a = Alpha.text;
    }
}
```

That isn't converted.

Use the value in your viewmodel property instead.